# How do I make some wpf resources (e.g. styles, brushes etc.) that are visible to all resource dictionaries?

Tags: wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

I am new to WPF and using resource dictionaries. I want to create some styles that are accessible to all resource dictionaries but I don't know what is the appropriate way to do that? 
I also want to know how to use resources in another resource dictionary in a resource dictionary.

Comment: Do you mean `Application.Resources`?

Comment: @dkozl: Yes, but I was also wondering what if the project is a user control project and there is no App.xaml file.

Comment: Is it a good idea to create a resource dictionary for the whole project and use merge on other dictionaries?

Comment: That's why every resource dictionary has [`MergedDictionaries`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.resourcedictionary.mergeddictionaries(v=vs.110).aspx)  property. So you can merge your general dictionary with more specific one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using `Application.Resources` in `App.xaml`. Create a `Resource Dictionary` where you want to store and just put your your `Resource Dictionary` name in the `source` of `ResourceDictionary`.

```
  <Application.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                    <ResourceDictionary Source="Your Resource Dictionary Name"/>
                </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </Application.Resources>
```